# Sphere-plane collision resolve

Tags: physics, trigonometry, collision

I want to write a c++ program that will calculate collision between sphere and plane.

The rule is that the angle of the falling object equals to angle of reflection.

What do I have for sphere:

```
//sphere coordinates and radius
float x;
float y;
float z;
float r;
//sphere velocity vector projections
float vx;
float vy;
float vz;
```

Plane is described by plane equation coefficients:

```
float A;
float B;
float C;
float D;
```

With sphere-plane collision **detection** I have no problem. But how to find velocity after collision?

[image]

What did I find:

[image]

So, ultimately I need to calculate updated values for `vx vy vz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation defining the plane is

```
Ax + By + Cz + D = 0
```

So the vector normal to the plane is

```
W = (A, B, C)
```

Normalize it:

```
n = W/|W|
```

Now take the velocity vector:

```
V = (vx, vy, vz)
```

Its component normal to the plane is

```
Vn = (V . n) n
```

and the rest of it, the part parallel to the plane is

```
Vp = V - Vn
```

We want to reverse the normal component and leave the parallel component unchanged:

```
V' = -Vn + Vp
```

which works out to

```
V' = V - 2(V . n)n
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, what do You mean by dot?

Comment: @ArturKlochko: The dot product. (a,b,c) . (x,y,z) = ax + by + cz

Comment: `Vn = (V • n) x n` where `x` is vector product, right?

Comment: @ArturKlochko: "Vector product"? `Vn = (V . n) n` is multiplication of a scalar by a vector.

Comment: Understood. If you do not mind I post another answer with c++ code based on Your answer

Answer (score 1):

@Beta’s answer on c++:

```
float wl = sqrt(plane->A*plane->A+plane->B*plane->B+plane->C+plane->C); // “W” vector length

float nx = plane->A/wl; //Normal components
float ny = plane->B/wl;
float nz = plane->C/wl;

float scope = (sphere->vx*nx + sphere->vy*ny + sphere->vz*nz)*2; // 2(V . n)

nx = nx*scope; // 2(V . n)n
ny = ny*scope;
nz = nz*scope;

sphere->vx -= nx; // V' = V - 2(V . n)n
sphere->vy -= ny;
sphere->vz -= nz;
```